# stop reading file when marker is reached

Tags: ocaml

I have the following code, just the basics of what i'm trying to do:

```
let ic = open_in "file.txt" in
try
  while true do
    let line = input_line ic in
    print_endline line
  done
with End_of_file -> close_in ic
```

what i want to do is read the file in to a string appending each line until i reach the word "stop_here" I tried a few ways of my own and got totally messed up.. this is on windows os.

thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

Inside the `while` loop, add a test `if line = "stop_here" then raise End_of_file`?

Refine it if you want to stop on a line that just *contains* this marker.